# How can I parse array in android to put values to polyline?

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, polyline

I have an array with positions. I wanted to parse this array to show polyline in google maps.

Here is an example:
how can I parse this array?

```
double [][] pos = {
                {3.7067858,-14.4728779},
                {3.7067858,-14.4728779},
                {3.7067858,-14.4728779},
                {3.7067858,-14.4728779},
                {3.7067858,-14.4728779},
                {3.7067858,-14.4728779},
                {3.7067858,-14.4728779}};

 PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            .add(new LatLng(pos[i][i]))
                    i++;  
        }
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Evan's answer, you can build your LatLng objects within your loop.

```
double[][] pos = { {3.7067858,-14.4728779}, ... };
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++){
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(pos[i][0], pos[i][1]));
}
Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

As a side note, a 2D array of doubles is fine for point lists. It is how LineStrings are defined in the GeoJSON specification.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a 2d array for position data doesn't make much sense what you should do is have an array of LatLng's:

```
LatLng[] pos = {new LatLng(3.7067858,-14.4728779), ..., ...};
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    for (LatLng l : pos){
        rectOptions.add(l);
    }
    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```